# VirtueMart Shopping Cart - Open a "Ask a question about this product" page in modal box?

Tags: virtuemart

How can I open a "Ask a question about this product" link in modal box with only fields without the entire template. The good example is the email button in the article, it only shows the needed fields to send the article as email. I am using VirtueMart v1.1.5. Could somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly understand how to do it. To the end of the link has to be add to parameters -

```
&tmpl=component&type=raw
```